# Magento - Show "Up-sells" thumbnails with grouped product thumbnails

Tags: magento

I want to show the thumbnails of the "up-sells" products with grouped product thumbnails, with a link to the specific "up-sells" product.

It will be used like a color selector (for t-shirts for example).

This picture explain a little bit how should be my screen...

http://www.fragento.org/images/fbfiles/images/produit_groupe.jpg

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly you could check to see what type the product is and then change the following

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'small_image')->resize(125)
```

to

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_link, 'thumbnail')->resize(125)
```

Comment: Thanks dan.codes, 
I don't want to replace the "Up-sell" product image, but to put this one near the thumbnails of the main product. 
I suppose I have to edit the file media.phtml

Comment: That don't solve my problem !! :( Still searching for solution !
Thanks a lot for help.